# How to create animated border on hover

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to create a hover effect like in this site:

http://themes.creiden.com/circleflip/blog-with-sidebar/

Just hover over the "More" link.

http://joxi.ru/uXHGU_3JTJBkDpt35Iw

So I tried to do something like this, but I have only this variant

http://jsfiddle.net/TY8CQ/

Code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Click the link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    padding: 100px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}


a{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    font: 14px/40px Tahoma;
    color: #39adf0;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #39adf0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;

}

a:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 0;
    background: #39adf0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

a:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #39adf0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

But in the example (in the website) the stroke appears in order and in all sides... How can I do this? CSS3 only? Maybe with jQuery?

Comment: Judging by the way the animation is being done, I'd say it's probably javascript.

Comment: Buddy, it's simple enough, you can get all the source code from the site you mentioned.  It's just a bit finicky and I'm not sure people are gonna help you "lift" someone elses code!  Basically you're on the wrong track in anycase as the effect you want to replicate consists of 4 elements not 2.  Use your web-inspectory/firebug to investigate and see what happens on 'hover' in the CSS

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element? There's 3 spans inside that link, one with text, and two with borders, which get transformed with transitions. It's more complex than your try, but it's all there for everyone to analyze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code, I copied from your sample website.

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RXGr/4/)

**Demo:**

```css
a {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 47px;
    display: table;
    padding: 6px 9px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #E32831;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
}

span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 23px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
}
a:hover span {
    color: #5a5a5a;
}
.btnBefore, .btnAfter {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: solid #e32831;
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0;
    -moz-transition: 0;
    -o-transition: 0;
    -ms-transition: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-color: #E32831;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
    a .btnBefore {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
a .btnAfter {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
a:hover .btnBefore {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
a:hover .btnAfter {
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

a:hover .btnAfter, a:hover .btnBefore {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s, border-top-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s;
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s, border-top-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s;
-moz-transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s, border-top-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s;
-o-transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s, border-top-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s;
-ms-transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.4s, border-bottom-right-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s, border-top-left-radius 0.1s ease 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <span class="text">Click the link</span>
    <span class="btnBefore"></span>
    <span class="btnAfter"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

### [et voila!](http://jsfiddle.net/KsvW7/3/)

You can actually get near enough using pure CSS, by using pseudo elements and animation keyframes. The benefits being reduced DOM clutter, no JS and the strict separation of concerns (sticking to CSS for styling).

Note the below example works in Chrome, add/remove the `-webkit-` vendor prefix as appropriate for other browsers ([**example for Chrome, FF**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsvW7/4/)).

HTML

```
<a href='#'>hover!</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    background:#E32831;
    padding:10px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:white;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
}
a:before, a:after {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    content:'';
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
a:before {
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    left:-100%;
    top:0;
    height:0px;
}
a:after {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    left:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:0px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes left-up {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        height:0;
    }
    50% {
        left:0;
        height:0;
    }
    100% {
        height:100%;
        left:0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes right-dn {
    0% {
        left:-100%;
        height:0;
    }
    50% {
        left:0;
        height:0;
    }
    100% {
        height:100%;
        left:0;
    }
}
a:hover {
    background:lightgrey;
    color:#808080;
}
a:hover:after, a:hover:before {
    -webkit-animation-duration:900ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
a:hover:after {
    -webkit-animation-name:left-up;
}
a:hover:before {
    -webkit-animation-name:right-dn;
}
```

Comment: nice method using only one html tag, **+1** from me!

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery I was able to re-create the behavior almost exactly: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/TY8CQ/6/)

```
$('a').append('<div class="borders" id="TL"></div><div class="borders" id="BL"></div><div class="borders" id="TR"></div><div class="borders" id="BR"></div>');

$('a').mouseover(function(){    
     $(this).stop().find('#TL, #BR').css("display","block").animate({width:"100%"},"fast", function(){ 
     $(this).siblings('#TR, #BL').css("display","block").animate({height:"100%"},"fast"); })}
).mouseout(function(){  
     $(this).find('#BL, #TR').animate({height:"0px"},"fast", function(){ 
     $(this).siblings('#BR, #TL').animate({width:"0px"},"fast")}
      ); 
 });

.borders { display: none; width: 1px; height: 1px; background: red; position: absolute; }
#TL { top: 0; left: 0; }
#BL { bottom: 0; left: 0; }
#TR { top: 0; right: 0; }
#BR { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS pseudo elements with transition properties. IF you want more on Border Animation, use SVG animations. I recommend you to take look at SVG animations. below is the nice article for SVG animations on border and demo of pure css animation.

```
<pre>http://jsfiddle.net/Mostwanted_cJ/F8uZE/<code>
```

[Border Animation Effect with SVG and CSS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/26/creating-a-border-animation-effect-with-svg-and-css/)